# ¿Cómo sombrear el resto de la pantalla cuando abro un menú?

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de sombrear el resto de la pantalla cuando abro un menú con JavaScript, el problema es que inputs, selects, buttons, etc.. no se sombrean, solamente al fondo se le aplica el sombreado. Este es mi código JavaScript para abrir y cerrar el menú:

```
////Function to open the menu
function openNav(element) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.overflow = 'hidden';
    if(screen.width < 577) {
        document.getElementById('sideNav').style.width = '310px';
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0, 0.6)";
        document.body.style.transition = "0.5s";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('sideNav').style.width = '350px';
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.6)";
    }
}

//Function to close the menu
function closeNav(element) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.overflow = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('sideNav').style.width = '0';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

Esto es el resultado que obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero y me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Tal vez con 'filter' en la etiqueta 'body', lo probaría rápidamente pero el código que has puesto no permite pruebas rápidas para replicar tu situación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta mejor agregando un ***overlay***. *Para referencia puedes ver este [enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_overlay.asp)*

De esta forma lo que pasará es que un div con fondo opaco semitransparente se colocará entre tu sideNav y la parte de detrás opacando todo lo demás.

Lo que tendrías que hacer es agregar en tu documento este elemento:

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Con estos estilos:

```
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Además agrega a los estilos de tu sideNav un `z-index: 3;`

Y en tu script cambia por esto:

```
function openNav(element) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.overflow = 'hidden';
    if(screen.width < 577) {
        document.getElementById('sideNav').style.width = '310px';
        document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('sideNav').style.width = '350px';
        document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
    }
}

function closeNav(element) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.overflow = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('sideNav').style.width = '0';
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}
```